# Stop image repositioning when window resize

Tags: html, css

First off, I'm new to HTML and CSS. I'm creating a web but when resizing the browser is troubling me. How do I make the textbox(and everything on my web) on the right side of the page to stay put whenever I resize the browser?

HTML

```
<body>

<div id="container" align="center">
<br />
<div id="header" >
    <img src="logo.jpg" align="left"/>

    <table align="right">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" maxlength="20" /></td>
            <td><img src="search.jpg" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
height:100%;
padding-bottom:40px;
overflow:hidden;
min-width: 100%;
}
#innerheader {
    width: 40%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#header {
    min-width: 80%;
    position: relative;
}
```

I'm stuck on this part for a day now. :(
I tried googling it but unfortunately I didn't come across to what I'm looking for.

Comment: try to change your page, header, container width from width:100%; to width:960px; or however many pixels you need.

Comment: It's working! :D But my header div repositioned to the left.. How do I fix this regardless of the window resizing?

Answer (score 2):

You can see this site , hope you find your answer 

the link is [here](http://bytes.com/topic/html-css/answers/96668-css-positioning-browser-resizing)